# awk syntax error: unexpected end of file

Tags: unix

I'm getting a:
**-bash: unexpected EOF while looking for match `'' 
-bash: syntax error: unexpected end of file**
error and I have no idea why. For some reason, it isn't telling me which line the error is on either. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
$ awk ‘BEGIN {
sent=0;
received=0;}

{
if($1 == ”s” && $19 == ”AGT”)
{sent++;}
else if($1 == “r” && $19 == ”AGT”)
{received++;}
}

END

{
printf “Packet Sent:%d”,sent;
printf “\n Packet Received:%d”,received;
printf “\n Packet Delivery Ratio:%.2f\n”,(sent/received)*100;
}’
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things:

You're using fancy quotes when you should be using regular ones. Note that `‘` is not the same as `'` and `“` is not the same as `"`. So you should fix those.

Also, your `awk` script has a syntax error, where the `{` for the `END` should be on the same line as the `END` itself, just like what you have for the `BEGIN`.

---

Here's the corrected script (which works on my machine, at least):

```
awk 'BEGIN {
sent=0;
received=0;}

{
if($1 == "s" && $19 == "AGT")
{sent++;}
else if($1 == "r" && $19 == "AGT")
{received++;}
}

END {
  printf "Packet Sent:%d",sent;
  printf "\n Packet Received:%d",received;
  printf "\n Packet Delivery Ratio:%.2f\n",(sent/received)*100;
}'
```